# more than one library with package name 'com.daimajia.slider.library' android studio

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to create an android Image Slider with library :
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider
but after I add the library to my project, gradle gave me this Error: more than one library with package name 'com.daimajia.slider.library'

I have below build.gradle file in my project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.korandco.irkhoone_mobile_app"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':bottom-bar')
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', version: '0.7.5.201505241946'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.0.3@aar'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
}
```

and gradle library :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    enforceUniquePackageName = false
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 15
        versionName "1.1.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1"
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you included it as a jar or library project?

Comment: Thank you, error has been fixed .I repeat my library dependencies in the project